# Mysql make a stored procedure from multiple stored procedures

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, union

## MySQL- Question

I have three stored procedures which gives same result set for different conditions and joining different tables.

ex

```
procedure_one(StartDate,EndDate);
procedure_two(StartDate,EndDate);
procedure_three(StartDate,EndDate);
```

I need an another stored procedure which will gives the result from above three stored procedures. simply union of above three stored procedures. I don't want the union of 3 queries instead i want union of 3 stored procedures. I googled but unable to find good solution.

I have made few attempts as follows.

first attempt

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE `MasterProcedure` (IN StartDate DATE,IN EndDate DATE)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @CALL procedure_one (StartDate,EndDate) UNION
        SELECT @CALL procedure_two (StartDate,EndDate) UNION
        SELECT @CALL procedure_three (StartDate,EndDate);
    END //
DELIMITER ;
```

second attempt

```
DELIMITER //
DECLARE var_val1 TEXT;
DECLARE var_val2 TEXT;
DECLARE var_val3 TEXT;
CREATE PROCEDURE `MasterProcedure` (IN StartDate DATE,IN EndDate DATE)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @CALL procedure_one (StartDate,EndDate) INTO @var_val1;
        SELECT @CALL procedure_two (StartDate,EndDate) INTO @var_val2;
        SELECT @CALL procedure_three (StartDate,EndDate) INTO @var_val3;
        SELECT @var_val1,@var_val2,@var_val3;
    END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Is there any workaround to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are stored procedures return a scalar value? What returning stored procedures?

Comment: @wchiquito They will return result set like name,date,shipped_date,order_number,invoice number etc..

Comment: I think MySQL currently does not support something like what you need. Try a new approach to achieve what you need.

Comment: @wchiquito Thanks bro. seems like it does not support. I will try to find an alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I think above feature is not implemented in MySQL. See [here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=10817) for more information.

I came up with following solution. But not sure it is the best approach to this problem.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE pro_1(IN param1 data_type,IN param2 data_type);
BEGIN
   CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp1 AS SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE $where1;
COMMIT;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

as above you can create next two procedures as follows.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE pro_2(IN param1 data_type,IN param2 data_type);
BEGIN
   CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp2 AS SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE $where2;
COMMIT;
END //
DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE pro_3(IN param1 data_type,IN param2 data_type);
BEGIN
   CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp3 AS SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE $where3;
COMMIT;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

So following is the master procedure which is union of above 3 procedures.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE master_pro(IN param1 data_type,IN param2 data_type);
BEGIN
   CALL pro_1(param1,param2);
   CALL pro_2(param1,param2);
   CALL pro_3(param1,param2);
   CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE master_temp AS (SELECT * FROM temp1) UNION ALL (SELECT *  FROM temp2) UNION ALL (SELECT * FROM temp3);
COMMIT;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

SO finally if you want to get any other results from master procedure you can do as follows.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE another_pro(IN param1 data_type,IN param2 data_type);
BEGIN
   CALL master_pro(param1,param2);
   SELECT columns_from_master_temp FROM master_temp WHERE where_clause;
COMMIT;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```