# How to union all the result of two stored procedure?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two stored procedure which returns something like this:

```
call proc1('Jack');
+------+------------+
| 3232 |   Admin    |
+------+------------+
| 3254 | SuperUser  |
+------+------------+
| 3264 | Admin      |
+------+------------+

call proc2('Martin');
+------+--------+
| 6345 | User   |
+------+--------+
| 6309 | Stuff  |
+------+--------+
```

How can I use combine the result of those two procedure and use the final result?

Comment: Do you want to do this in SQL or PHP

Comment: @RiggsFolly In SQL, but if it is not possible, then in PHP.

Comment: @RiggsFolly `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'union all call proc2('Martin')' at line 1`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Please reopen my question, that question is about SQL SERVER.

Comment: Yea, just noticed that, my mistake

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19580499/mysql-make-a-stored-procedure-from-multiple-stored-procedures

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thx for the link you provided. Also I have a totally different question. I have a `LIMIT` clause in my query, I need to set something to it which don't limit the result at all. Something like `LIMIT -1`, but it throws syntax error. *(Noted that I cannot remove that `LIMIt` clause)*

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you, You can create the new procedure and invoke both procedure proc1 and proc2 inside the new procedure and also perform union operation inside new procedure by creating a temparory table.
for example:

```
create Procedure get_union_proc(your_parameter ...)
BEGIN
Insert INTO #Temp_table1 exec proc1;
Insert INTO  #Temp_rable2 exec proc2;
select * from Temp_table1
union
select * from Temp_table2
END get_union_proc
```

I hope it would be helpful.

Comment: What's `exec`? I don't use SQL SERVER. I use MySQL

Comment: If you are using MYSQL then you must use CALL keyword for instead of EXEC

Answer (score -2):

You Need to create a temporary table and fetch results from the temporary table.

```
INSERT INTO #TempTable
EXEC StoredProc0;
INSERT INTO #TempTable
EXEC Storedproc1;
```

Select * from TempTable;