# Make stored procedure from stored procedure mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I used this solution [Mysql make a stored procedure from multiple stored procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19580499/mysql-make-a-stored-procedure-from-multiple-stored-procedures)

I have 2 stored procedures which I want to make stored procedure with 2 stored procedures in 1 stored procedure.

This is procedure 1

```
CREATE DEFINER=`brambang`@`%` PROCEDURE `buyer_statistic_monthly`(IN paramdatefrom datetime, IN paramdateto datetime)
BEGIN
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp2 as SELECT 
count_PBR as PBR,
count_PUL as PUL,
count_PEX as PEX,
count_ID as pesanan
FROM 
(SELECT 
(select -- om.createdby, om.quantity, x1.count_
count(distinct om.createdby) as count_pbr
from (select count(xx.count_) as count_
from (select count(createdby) as count_
from order_match where
order_status_Id in (4, 5, 6, 8)
group by createdby having count(createdby) = 1) xx ) x1,
(select createdby from order_match where order_status_id in (4, 5, 6, 8)
 group by createdby having count(createdby) = 1) yy, order_match om where yy.createdby = om.createdby and
order_status_id in (4, 5, 6, 8) and
om.createdAt >= paramdatefrom and om.createdAt <= paramdateto
and NOT EXISTS
(select 1 from order_match om2 where om.createdby = om2.createdby
and order_status_id in (4, 5, 6, 8) and om2.createdAt < paramdatefrom)) count_PBR,
(SELECT count(distinct om.createdby) as count_PUL
from (select count(xx.count_) as count_
from (select count(createdby) as count_
from order_match where order_status_id in (4, 5, 6, 8)
group by createdby having count(createdby) > 1 ) xx ) x1,
(select createdby from order_match
where order_status_id in (4, 5, 6, 8)
group by createdby having count(createdby) > 1 ) yy,
order_match om where yy.createdby = om.createdby
and order_status_id in (4, 5, 6, 8) and om.createdAt >= paramdatefrom
and om.createdAt <= paramdateto
and EXISTS (select 1 from order_match om2 where om.createdby = om2.createdby
and order_status_id in (4, 5, 6, 8) and om2.createdAt <= paramdateto)) count_PUL,
(SELECT
count(distinct om.createdby) as count_PEX
from
order_match om
where om.order_status_id in (4,5,6,8)
and om.createdAt <= paramdateto
and om.createdAt >= paramdatefrom
and EXISTS (select 1 from order_match om2
where om.createdby = om2.createdby
and om2.createdAt < paramdatefrom and
om2.order_status_id in (4, 5, 6, 8))) count_PEX,
(SELECT count(id) from order_match where order_status_id in (4, 5, 6, 8) and createdAt between paramdatefrom
AND paramdateto) count_ID) a
;

END
```

This is procedure 2

```
CREATE DEFINER=`brambang`@`%` PROCEDURE `TNP_PEMBELI_PERCENTAGE`(IN paramdatefrom datetime, paramdateto datetime)
BEGIN
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp1 as 
SELECT 
    result_a / result_b * 100 AS percentage_PBR,
    100 - (result_a / result_b * 100) AS percentage_PEX
FROM
    (SELECT 
        (select -- om.createdby, om.quantity, x1.count_
                count(distinct om.createdby) as count_pbr
                from (select count(xx.count_) as count_
from (select count(createdby) as count_
from order_match where
order_status_Id in (4, 5, 6, 8)
group by createdby having count(createdby) = 1) xx ) x1,
(select createdby from order_match where order_status_id in (4, 5, 6, 8)
 group by createdby having count(createdby) = 1) yy, order_match om where yy.createdby = om.createdby and
order_status_id in (4, 5, 6, 8) and
om.createdAt >= paramdatefrom and om.createdAt <= paramdateto
and NOT EXISTS
(select 1 from order_match om2 where om.createdby = om2.createdby
and order_status_id in (4, 5, 6, 8) and om2.createdAt < paramdatefrom)) result_a,
            (SELECT 
                    COUNT(DISTINCT om.createdby) AS count
                FROM
                    (SELECT 
                    COUNT(xx.count_) AS count_
                FROM
                    (SELECT 
                    COUNT(createdby) AS count_
                FROM
                    order_match
                WHERE
                    order_status_Id IN (4 , 5, 6, 8)
                GROUP BY createdby) xx) x1, (SELECT 
                    createdby
                FROM
                    order_match
                GROUP BY createdby) yy, order_match om
                WHERE
                    yy.createdby = om.createdby
                        AND order_status_id IN (4 , 5, 6, 8)
                        AND om.createdAt >= paramdatefrom
                        AND om.createdAt <= paramdateto) result_b,
            (SELECT 
                    COUNT(DISTINCT om.createdby) AS count
                FROM
                    order_match om
                WHERE
                    om.order_status_id IN (4 , 5, 6, 8)
                        AND om.createdAt <= paramdateto
                        AND om.createdAt >= paramdatefrom
                        AND EXISTS( SELECT 
                            1
                        FROM
                            order_match om2
                        WHERE
                            om.createdby = om2.createdby
                                AND om2.createdAt < paramdatefrom
                                AND om2.order_status_id IN (4 , 5, 6, 8))) result_c
    ) a;
    END
```

based on 2 procedure above, I wrote this stored procedure so that 2 procedure can run in 1 stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`brambang`@`%` PROCEDURE `TES`(IN paramdatefrom datetime, IN paramdateto datetime)
BEGIN
CALL buyer_statistic_monthly(paramdatefrom, paramdateto);
CALL TNP_PEMBELI_PERCENTAGE(paramdatefrom,paramdateto);
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE master_temp AS (SELECT * FROM temp1) UNION ALL (SELECT * FROM temp2);
END
```

but I get an error

> Error Code: 1222. The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

I've tried with @vvvv4d solution, but still I get that error.

Comment: It is trivial to compare the number of columns created in 2 tables. You could improve your help chances if you tidied up this code mess and provided sample data(as text).

Comment: i think the main focus is why it cant be done when i called 2 sp in just 1 sp, not the queries inside each store procedure, because there's no problem with each store procedure (each sp can be running normally)

Comment: -Just to confirm you have checked that the number and datatypes of the columns in temp1 and temp2 are the same? AND have you tried the create master_temp using only temp1 and only temp2 and there were no problems?

Comment: number of coloumns between temp1 and temp2 are different, but is mysql cant afford that? i just want to put all of the sp with same parameter but different process, so i made 1 sp contain more than 1 sp

Comment: same things for each sp are only the parameter, the process for each sp are different (including the coloumn). but did mysql cant do that? i just want to put all of the sp with the same parameter into 1 sp

Comment: 'number of coloumns between temp1 and temp2 are different, but is mysql cant afford that?' - NO , they eother have to be the same or you need to provide dummy columns to make them the same. (ie what the error is telling you)

Comment: oh i see, so the way all of the sp can into in just one sp is manually write the queries one by one, is that true?

Comment: Not at all.....

Comment: is there any solution for my issue? how to combine all of the sp with same parameter but different output coloumn into just only 1 sp

Comment: The solution is  provide dummy columns to make them the same

Answer (score 1):

The `Temp1` and `Temp2` *tables* don't have exactly the same **columns** which is required to use `union`

You need to make sure it's something like:

```
select PEX, PBR from Temp1
union
select  percentage_PEX,  percentage_PBR from Temp2
```

If your going to use `select *` the tables have to **have the same columns** that your going to `union` together.

You got

> > > Error Code: 1222. The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Because `Temp1` has columns `Temp2` **doesn't** have.

Comment: is it okay if i change the UNION ALL to just UNION?

Comment: No that won't fix the problem. Union will only return unique records so even if both tables have the same row the final result will be one row. If you use union all it returns all rows and you will see duplicates if both tables have the same row.

Comment: let me try it, my mysql just error, i will mark this as an answer if this true, thankyou very much

Comment: why its say Error Code: 1050. Table 'temp2' already exists

Comment: Temp2 is already created and your trying to create it again. Drop it then try to create it again.

Comment: yes i forgot to drop it, after i drop it, and its still says Error Code: 1222. The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns